# How do I convert SWF into a PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, flash, swf

I want to convert a SWF document to into PDF.

The SWF can be found here (*Update: no longer available*):

```
http://www.imsindia.com/online/tests/test_111.swf
```

And I would like to be able to convert or save it down as a PDF. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Hello,
this has nothing to do with programming. Please, next time consider other websites.

Comment: I think he means convert a PDF document to SWF, which the sample does.

Comment: URL shorteners are murder!

Comment: Why do you need to do that? It's a pain.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do it, I would use SWF to FLA decompiler, open the file in Adobe Flash and try to somehow export it from Flash.

The downside is, you need (1) the decompiler, which is not (legally) for free, and (2) the same applies for Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 0):

At first blush I'd say try a print to pdf driver like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/). Failing that, a [SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) might work as suggested above. After that, I'm way out of my depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the SWF into a HTML file and then use adobe acrobat pro to convert the HTML file to a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (maybe not practical but working):

You can convert the SWF to image files (e.g. JPEG) and then copy them to Word (or Numbers) and export as PDF.