# Convert SWF/FLA back to PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, flash, swf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert SWF into a PDF?](https://superuser.com/questions/36517/how-do-i-convert-swf-into-a-pdf)

I have a number of graphics and text only SWF and FLA files that I'd like to convert to PDF preserving the text and formatting. Printing to PDF from Flash Player seems to flatten everything into an image without preserving the text.

I've got a large number of those files, so it would be quite nice to have a automatable/console utility to do the job.

Appreciate any help or pointers. Thanks!

EDIT: It seems like most SWF files were created with [pdf2swf](http://www.swftools.org/), so I'm hoping there is a similar tool for doing a reverse conversion.

Comment: um for fla the paid apps do the editing....for swf they can't be edited short of disassembly.  that's kind of the point.

Comment: It isn't because 1) I have the FLA files that do not contain anything but type and graphics (I believe they were created with the SWFTools' pdf2swf, actually) and 2) there are about 700 files total, one for each page, respectively. Decompiling and using Adobe Flash would be one heck of a way to spend the weekend. I would prefer a console-based scriptable solution, if possible.

Comment: Gee, thanks. This question has little to do with the supposed 'duplicate'. Print to PDF? Flash player renders text into bitmaps. Flash the authoring tool? I am not doing 700 pages manually.